# Finding the optimal point of an manually constructed ROC curve

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, roc

I have 8 different diagnostic metric cut offs that I have calculated the True Positive Rate and False Positive Rate for. I have then plotted the different diagnostic metric points on a manually constructed ROC curve (just using ggplot and TPR vs FP).
Data is:

```
Metric<-c("zero", "CORNER", "DOL", "GE", "K", "M", "F", "H", "L", "G")
   FPR<-c(0, 0.11, 0.26, 0.07, 0.5, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.29, 0.03)
   TPR<-c(0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8)
   #let us put these all into one table

    FinalTable<-data.frame(Metric, FPR, TPR)
```

The code for the graph is below:

```
    ggplot(FinalTable, aes(FPR, TPR)) + 
      geom_point()
```

Example: [image]

I am trying to find the optimal point on this manually constructed ROC curve but I cannot seem to find the way to do it.

Anybody know how to do this (I do not want to construct multiple ROC curves as that would only tell me the youden index or AUC of 1 specific diagnostic cut off)?

Answer (score 0):

You could weigh the FPR and TPR equally and abstract them like TPR-FPR and find the maximum score, like this:

```r
Metric<-c("zero", "CORNER", "DOL", "GE", "K", "M", "F", "H", "L", "G")
FPR<-c(0, 0.11, 0.26, 0.07, 0.5, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.29, 0.03)
TPR<-c(0, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8)
#let us put these all into one table
FinalTable<-data.frame(Metric, FPR, TPR)

# Determine score
FinalTable$score = FinalTable$TPR - FinalTable$FPR

# find max score
FinalTable[which.max(FinalTable$score),]
#>    Metric  FPR TPR score
#> 10      G 0.03 0.8  0.77
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This means that an FPR of 0.03 and TPR of 0.8 is your optimal threshold if you handle the weights equally. Check this question and answer for more info: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123124/how-to-determine-the-optimal-threshold-for-a-classifier-and-generate-roc-curve

Answer (score 0):

I revised this a bit based on the response to the answer:

If I am following what you are doing, you have ten different types of tests with 10 different true positive rates and false negative rates, one of which is no testing -- no one tests positive. You could also add the point (1,1), which is everyone is assumed to have tested positive.

Some of the tests are not useful as there is another test with a higher TPR but the same or lower FPR or a lower FPR and the same or higher TPR.
I just eyeballed it and the convex hull can be formed by connecting tests
{1,10,3}.  People often think of the optimal test as the one that minimizes the sum of the FPR and FNR (1-TPR), which you can easily determine as 80% TPR and a 3% FPR.  Nevertheless, it depends on costs of a FP versus the benefits of TP. You can get a higher TPR (90%) at the expensive of a higher FPR (26%).

You can create a traditional ROC curve by connecting the points {1,10,3,11}, where the eleventh point is "everyone tests positive".  Every point on this ROC curve is obtainable by randomly assigning people to a different test with a certain weight.  For example, if you only test half the population with a certain test and assume the rest are negative, the FPR and TPR are both one-half of what they would be if everyone was given the test.

For cosmetic purposes, one can fit a smooth curve through the points and below is one approach to doing so.  It doesn't make sense to do so though as it implies that the set of tests have a predictive power that they do not have: the difference between the smooth black curve and the red line (the piecewise linear one) is not obtainable in practice.  If you look for the point that minimizes the FPR + 1- FNR across every point on the red line, it returns the same value as if you just look across the three tests.

```
FinalTable$id <- 1:10
FinalTable[order(FinalTable$TPR), ]
par(pty = "s", ann = TRUE, mfrow = c(1, 1), bg = "white", mai = 1 * c(1, 1, 1, 1))
plot(FinalTable$FPR, FinalTable$TPR,
     typ = "p", xlab = "FPR",
     ylab = "TPR", xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1)
)


lines(c(FinalTable$FPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1), c(FinalTable$TPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1),
      typ = "l",
      col = "darkred", lwd = 2
)

opt <- which.min(FinalTable$FPR + 1 - FinalTable$TPR)
points(FinalTable$FPR[opt], FinalTable$TPR[opt], pch = 19, col = "darkgreen", cex = 2)

grid <- seq(1, 4, length = 100)
s1 <- smooth.spline(1:4, c(FinalTable$FPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1), all.knots = T, penalty = 0)
s2 <- smooth.spline(1:4, c(FinalTable$TPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1), all.knots = T, penalty = 0)
predict(s2)
x2 <- predict(s1, grid)[[2]]
y2 <- predict(s2, grid)[[2]]
lines(x2, y2)

x <- seq(0, 1, length = 1000)
y <- approx(c(FinalTable$FPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1), c(FinalTable$TPR[c(1, 10, 3)], 1), x)[[2]]

opt2 <- which.min(x - y)
points(x[opt2], y[opt2], pch = 1, col = "darkRed", cex = 3)
```

produces [image: roc curve]

Comment: This is great and thank you very much. Is there any way of drawing a curved line of best fit? I tried creating a code for this, almost like imitating an Mock ROC curve

Comment: you could add the point (1,1) which is every one is assumed to have tested positive.  It will still be line segments though, which  I think it is because your tests are discrete values.  It is not something like taking someone's temperature where the test result is inherently continuous.

Comment: Please see revised answer which elaborates on the points above.

Comment: This is brilliant. I tried adding text labels to this but for some reason my code is causing overlap of the text because some of them are so close together.

Comment: text(TPR ~FPR, labels=Metric, data=FinalTable, cex=0.3, pos=1, font=4)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of getting around this without using a ggplot or ggrepel packages?

Comment: Maybe just label points 1,3 and 10:

Comment: text(TPR[(1,3,10)] ~FPR[(1,3,10)], labels=Metric[(1,3,10)], data=FinalTable, cex=0.3, pos=1, font=4). should work

Comment: weird, nothing wrong with the code from what I can deduce but it keep saying there's an error with a comma. I've played around with it and it is still showing it.

Comment: sorry, it should be: text(TPR[c(1,3,10)] ~FPR[c(1,3,10)], labels=Metric[c(1,3,10)], data=FinalTable, cex=0.3, pos=1, font=4).  The way to think about it is you are selecting the first, third and 10 items in the vectors TPR, FPR and Metric and you need a vector to do that.

Comment: This works reasonably will but you may want to fine tune:               text(TPR[c(1,3,10)] ~FPR[c(1,3,10)], labels=Metric[c(1,3,10)], data=FinalTable, cex=1, pos=4, font=4,col="blue")